# "End of Statement Expected" in VBScript file

Tags: vbscript, hta, eula

Been writing a script for showing and logging acceptance of a End User License Agreement for use over Active directory. It's written into a .hta file and uses VBScript for the most part.

I've run into a lot of issues that I have fixed so far but this last one has got me stumped.

When the file is run it gives me an

> "End of Statement Expected"

error for line 35 of the script which is:

```
27    For Each ln in dict.Items
28      If ln = UserName Then
29        wasFound = true
30      End If
31    Next
32    If wasFound Then
33      WScript.Quit()
34      Else
35        Call DisableTaskMgr
36      Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & wmiNS)
37      Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
38      For Each objItem in colItems
39        objItem.terminate(1)
40      Next
41    End If
```

I have no idea what it's asking me to change.

The full file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/crQxcBNW)

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
System = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"
dim currentDir : currentDir = objShell.CurrentDirectory
UserName = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
pathToDirectory = currentDir & "/store/directory.txt"
wasFound = false
row = 0
Version = "V1.0"
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set directoryfile = fso.OpentextFile(pathToDirectory, 1)
dim strComputer : strComputer = "."
dim wmiNS : wmiNS = "/root/cimv2"
dim wmiQuery : wmiQuery = "Select processID from win32_process where name = 'explorer.exe'"
dim objWMIService 
dim colItems 
dim objItem 
dim strOUT     

Do Until directoryfile.AtEndOfStream
  line = directoryfile.Readline
  dict.Add row, line
  row = row + 1
Loop

directoryfile.Close

For Each ln in dict.Items
  If ln = UserName Then
    wasFound = true
  End If
Next
If wasFound Then
  window.close
Else
  Call DisableTaskMgr
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & wmiNS)
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
  For Each objItem in colItems
    objItem.terminate(1)
  Next
End If

sub DisableTaskMgr
  objShell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
  objShell.RegWrite System & "/DisableTaskMgr", 1, "REG_DWORD"
end sub

sub EnableTaskMgr
  objShell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
  objShell.RegWrite System & "/DisableTaskMgr", 0, "REG_DWORD"
end sub

sub RestartExplorerExe
  objShell.Run "explorer.exe"
end sub

sub Logon
  Call EnableTaskMgr
  If Not (fso.FileExists(currentDir & "/store/" & LCase(UserName) & ".csv")) Then
    Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(currentDir & "/store/" & LCase(UserName) & ".csv", 2, True)
    objFile.close
  Else
  End If
  Set ObjOpenFile = fso.OpenTextFile(currentDir & "/store/" & UserName & ".csv", 8, -2)
  objOpenFile.WriteLine(UserName & "," & Now & "," & Version)
  objOpenFile.Close
  Set objOpenFile = fso.OpenTextFile(currentDir & "/store/directory.txt", 8, -2)
  objOpenFile.WriteLine(UserName)
  objOpenFile.Close
  Call RestartExplorerExe
  window.close   
end sub

sub Logoff
  objShell.Run "shutdown /l"
end sub
```

If you guys find any other silly errors in the code I'd appreciate the help with those too, been working on this script for about 3 months.

EDIT: Most issues have now been fixed but I have run into a very odd issue that wasn't appearing before. Inside the CSV file that is created into the Logon method it is supposed to write {username},{date},{version number} but instead it writes random asian characters into the file.

Comment: You realise that `Dim variable = something` is incorrect syntax in VBScript, you cannot `Dim` and assign on the same line unless you use this little cheat `Dim variable : variable = something`. You have a lot of them in the code but because you have `On Error Resume Next` set they will be ignored and the next line will attempt to run. Also `OpenTextFile()` file needs a physical path not a virtual one, so that will also error. Personally I'd comment out `On Error Resume Next` until you have the script behaving as you would expect.

Comment: You are also mixing variable and object variable assignments, `Set` is only used to assign instances of objects. A string in VBScript is not classed as an object instance but a simple type instead. Fact is `End of Statement Expected` could actually be coming from a dozen or more errors you currently have.

Comment: @Lankymart By Physical path do you mean that I need to have the full path example: "C:\..\..\store\directory.txt"?

Comment: Yes, the path style you are using there *(in terms of Windows)* is a virtual path expected by a web server not a local / physical one. just writing `"/store/directory.txt"` the `FileSystemObject` has no concept of what it's working directory is, you always need to specify a full path. Commenting out `On Error Resume Next` should highlight most of these for you to dig into.

Comment: Not sure why you would indent there but each to there own, usually indentation denotes code is inside a procedure, conditional statement or loop. Adding an extra indent after the declarations does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`On Error Resume Next` was causing my errors to be hidden. This was causing my inability to fix the script.

Taking that away gave me all the information I needed to fix all issues.